# Is it possible to implement a Mobile Chat service that can communicate with outside "servers"?

Tags: xmpp, chat, messaging

We have a need to build a chatting service from our mobile (HTML5 based) application to give our users ability to communicate with multiple vendors (not all at the same time). Assuming, each vendor has own XMPP based chatting server running or assuming they use a service like OLARK, ZOPIM or LiveCHAT, is it possible for our service to connect and redirect messages from our mobile client to their servers? (also assuming that vendors are willing to work with our service to exchange messages with our customers)

Vendors might already be running a chat service on their websites in which case the messages we redirect from our client service also can flow into the same stream.

Please share any knowledge to help me unravel this technical challenge. I am new to messaging and available products in this space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be very easy to do provided the vendors who wish to stick with their current chat services have an API you can attach to, you may need a way to interact with many different chat services, but that too should not be very difficult to overcome

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. At least I now know it is possible to do it. Can you please share any more technical details on how we do this integration? What to look for or road blocks etc.?

Comment: Well, I would say that one of your biggest obsticles will be sending each service exactly what they need to send a message as they may be different, so you will need a function which identifies the service(many plausible ways of doing this) and then sends the required data for that service to that service. Different services may require different data for different functions, you will need to get documentation from the vendors on their current chat services to understand how the interactions will need to be completed

Comment: Is the chat application service providers (such as Olark, HipChat etc.) that give us the authentication / key to call the API's for us to connect or will it be the businesses that are using the chat application to that need to allow messages to flow into their stream? Thanks for help in advance.